# How to parse Date coming from SQLite DB in java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am trying to parse date coming from db(2014-06-11 16:58:12.903) like following

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("tr-TR"));
String tarih = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Created");
tarih = tarih.replace("T", " ");
Object.Created = dateFormat.parse(tarih);
```

Also code in below returns "Fri Dec 04 16:58:12 EET 16"

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("tr-TR"));
String tarih = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(field.getName()));
Object.Created = dateFormat.parse(tarih);
```

This method returns me a date like  "Wed Jun 11 16:58:12 EEST 2014"

How can i get date like dd-MM-YYYY >11-06-2014

Answer (score 0):

// Add the below lines of code in your method.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
return fmtOut.format(tarih);
```

Please note this factor about month. (To get today's date)

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

 int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1; // INCREMENT MONTH VALUE BY 1 (we get 0 for january and 11 for december)
 month_name = map_instance.findMonthName(month+"");
 int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

// The issue in year value could be because of the data retrived from database

```
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("tr-TR"));
    String tarih ="";
    try
    {
    tarih = dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Created"));
    }catch (ParseException e) {
    tarih = "";
    }
log.w("Data from database",tarih);
    tarih = tarih.replace("T", " ");
    Object.Created = tarih;
```

Comment: Thanks. this seems like working but i didnt get one thing it parsed            "2014-06-11 00:00:00" like "Fri Dec 04 00:00:00 EET 16" do you think is there something wrong with year ?

Comment: Reason is - Month starts with 0 till 11. Number 11 represents December month as per the SimpleDateFormat Class.

Comment: thanks but i ment year which is 2014 but in parsed date there is 04 and 16? this part i didnt get

Comment: @BahadirGul, Try with the mentioned code and if you still face the issue, mention the log value you get from DB